# Is a replacement fluorescent-tube light not working because it draws too much current?

Tags: lighting

My daughter had 2 incandescent fixtures on one switch in the garage. She changed one of them for a two tube fluorescent fixture, but the fluorescent fixture won't work - it's wired correctly. Is the incandescent drawing too much current?

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the involved boxes?

Answer (score 3):

> **Is the incandescent drawing too much current?**

No.

If it was, the circuit breaker would trip. This would only happen in the case of a serious fault in the fixture (or incorrect wiring). You would probably know if a circuit breaker had tripped.

The largest two-tube fixture would be 2 x 6-foot tubes. That would be rated about 140W. On a 110 volt AC supply that fixture draws a current of about 1.3 Amps. Most circuits will be rated for a maximum current many times higher than that.

Comment: The largest fixture I've seen (other than VHO exotica) is a dual 8' HO at about 220 watts.   Still not an issue.  The very common 2-tube 4 foot fluorescent is 65-90 watts depending on vintage, about the same as an incandescent bulb.  (and SO much more light!)  The LED replacements for the common 4' fluorescent light will be more like 30-40 watts.

Answer (score 2):

A few common problems that could be the cause:

- Some fluorescents can have a hard time starting if the temperature is really cold.
- Another common problem is not matching the bulbs to the starter type if the fixture didn't include the bulbs. The length and wattage aren't the only things that need to match.
- Rapid Start and some Instant Start fixtures must be connected to an electrical ground in order to start properly.
- The switch may be the problem.  Most compact fluorescent lamps cannot be used with dimmers, and will not function properly or at all when connected to these circuits. Similar problem with photocell, timer, or motion sensor switches.

Some good troubleshooting guidance here: http://nemesis.lonestar.org/reference/electricity/fluorescent/trouble.html